# Relation between Hodge star operator of two related metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $g,h$ be two Riemannian metric on $M$ related by $g=h+\phi$ where $\phi$ is a symmetric $(0,2)$-tensor and $g$ transforms $h$-orthonormal frame $\{e_i\}$ to $g$-orthonormal frame $\{a_i e_i\}$ for $a_i\in \Bbb R$. Then

> How $\star_g$ related to $\star_h$?

Update: Somewhere I read that if A is a $n\times n$-matrix,
and if $e_i\in T_pM$, then
$$\star(Ae_1\wedge\cdots\wedge Ae_k)=\det(A)\star(e_1\wedge\cdots\wedge e_k),\quad n=\dim M, k\leq n$$
Is this equivalent to my question?

Comment: Since any two metrics are related in this way (for $\phi=g-h$, which is certainly symmetric), you cannot expect to get a reasonable answer to this question.

Comment: The question has been updated.

Comment: What does "$g$ transforms $h$-orthonormal frame $\{e_i\}$ to $g$-orthonormal frame $\{a_ie_i\}$" mean?

Comment: $h(e_i,e_i)=g(ae_i,ae_i)=1$.